# How can I block GPSD from communicating out?

Tags: firewall, iptables, gpsd

I have two computers; one running gpsd and one using `gpspipe -w 192.168.90.1` to query the data.

GPSD listens on port 2947 and I want to block it with iptables. I've tried so many rules, but I can still see output from gpspipe and I don't expect that.

The main rules I started out with was

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o usb0 -p tcp --dport 2947 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o usb0 -p udp --dport 2947 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i usb0 -p tcp --dport 2947 -j DROP 
iptables -A INPUT -i usb0 -p udp --dport 2947 -j DROP
```

I've also tried the `FORWARD` chain with no luck. The man page for iptables is also confusing.

I need to make it so nothing goes out on port 2947 at all, and iptables seems completely inept at this. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to make it so nothing goes out on port 2947 at all,

To start with, as far as firewall rules go, GPSD isn't "communicating out" because it's not initiating the connection – gpspipe is. This matters because 1) packets and connections have a *pair* of port numbers, i.e. ports have a direction; 2) the *first* packet matters the most and it's what you start rule-writing from, which in this case is an 'INPUT' packet from GPSD's perspective.

When blocking traffic, if you drop the initial packet on input, there is usually no point in blocking further packets on output – they won't even be generated. (Whereas if you *don't* block the initial input packet, with TCP it might accidentally lead to a "SYN flood" as the server ends up with many half-established connections.)

Most importantly, the reply packets that GPSD does send out won't have `--dport 2497` – that will be their *source* port, so if you were doing stateless filtering, your 'OUTPUT' rules would say `--sport` instead.

> and iptables seems completely inept at this. Am I doing something wrong?

iptables rules are processed top-down, and the `-A` command **appends rules at the bottom**. In your example, you're just blindly adding rules at the end without actually checking what else is already there – it doesn't matter if you've added 10 of the same "deny" if the ruleset has an "allow" rule higher up in the list, as the first matching rule wins.

(This is my strong guess because every typical ruleset works like this: allow `lo` loopback communications, allow established, allow ICMP, allow other ports needed, drop everything else.)

Run `iptables -S` to check what rules you currently have, or `iptables -vnL` to see the line numbers so that you could insert a new rule at the specific position you need (or perhaps *delete* an existing rule that allows the traffic; no point in adding "deny X" if you have "allow X, deny all").

`-A` as well as `-I` (which inserts at the top) both take an optional line number to add the new rule after/before.

Another, probably better way would be to `iptables-save > somefile`, edit the file – you can see your ruleset all at once that way – then load it back using `iptables-restore`.

Comment: That is a very useful explanation. One of the variations I tired was `-I OUTPUT 1` to put the rules at the very top, which wasn't working either. I tried dozens of variations of this frankly stupid tool. Why in the world they designed networking rules to follow waterfall logic is beyond me.

Comment: I believe the kids these days call that a "skill issue".

Comment: Yeah; Rusty Russel's design and UI "skills"